# 「お気に入り」が「ブックマーク」に変わりました

Tags: 討議

この投稿は、@Adam Lear さんが Meta Stack Exchange に投稿された "[Favorites are now known as Bookmarks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347558/314875)" の和訳です。

どうぞご編集くださいませ m_ _m。

---

**本文**

以前に[MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network)でお伝えしましたが、「お気に入り」機能の名称が「ブックマーク」に変更されました。今回の変更により、本機能の使用方法と名前から期待する実際の動作がより明確になったと思います。

本機能を既に使用している場合は、名前とアイコン以外の変更は特にありません。あなたが「お気に入り」機能をこれまで使ったことがなかった場合には...、まあ、今は別の名前になっています。

質問ページの古いUIと新しいUIの比較は次の通りです：

[image]

「ユーザープロフィール」ページのタブ名も「ブックマーク」に変更されましたが、以前と同じ場所にあり、同じ機能を持ちます。

また、新しい検索演算子: `inbookmarks`が追加されました。 既存の検索演算子: `infavorites` の置き換えとなりますが、どちらでも同じ結果が得られます。

質問やコメント、バグレポートは、英語でしたら[MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347558/314875)に、日本語でしたらこちらに、どうぞお気軽に＼(^o^)／。

Answer (score 4):

まだ一つもブックマークを登録していない状態で `inbookmarks:mine` と検索すると、すべての質問がヒットするようです。本来なら "0件" で結果が表示されることを期待します。
(MSE にも [回答として報告済み](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347582) です)

Answer (score 3):

ヘルプページ https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/searching も書き直しが必要です。

> `infavorites:mine` (または任意のユーザー ID) は、自分 (または入力したユーザー) がお気に入りに追加した質問のみを返します。

---

追記@2020/05/19

以下の通り反映完了です
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 参考までに、元投稿の MSE でも同様の指摘が挙がっています。 - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347561