# ヘルプページのユーザー演算子に関する説明が古いままになっている

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

ヘルプページ「[検索の方法は？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)」の検索演算子 `in:saves`（[旧 `inbookmarks:mine`](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3323/32986)）の説明が `infavorites:mine` のままとなっています。

> - `infavorites:mine` (または任意のユーザー ID) は、自分 (または入力したユーザー) がお気に入りに追加した質問のみを返します。

[Meta Stack Exchangeのヘルプページ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching)では以下のように `in:saves` の説明となっているため、書き直す必要があると思います。

> - `in:saves` returns posts that you have saved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

以下の通り反映が完了しました。

[image: ユーザー演算子]